# android server connection over same network

Tags: android, sockets

I am making a cloud based android app wherein i have to send data from my android app to my server from time to time. The sockets work well when i test my app on my phone with the USB cable, both(computer and phone) connected to the same network. When i test the app by running the server on my computer and app on my phone, both connected by the same router, there is some problem and the connection is not made. I am not able to figure out why this is happening when the app works fine with the cable connected in debugging mode.
I have made a subclass of application for my socket to get hold of the socket on any activity.
My client code is as follows.

```
package augID.main;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

public class socketApp extends Application {

    public static String serverIpAddress = "172.16.83.3";
    public static int REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT = 54321;
    public Socket socket;

  public void onCreate(){
        createConnection();   
  }
  public void createConnection(){
      Log.d("Client", "Connection");
      try {
            socket = new Socket(serverIpAddress, REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT);
            Log.d("Client", "Connection to server made");
         } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
             Log.d("server","could not connect");
            e1.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e1) {
             Log.d("server","could not connect");
            e1.printStackTrace();
         }
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your router or firewall's blocking the connection?  If you haven't done it already, go into your router and forward port 54321 to the PC who's running the server.  Also, grab Wireshark and look for the connection request from your phone.

Hope this helps.